# How to popoulate recursive schema references Mongodb, Mongoose, Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

Using mongoose and Express with mongodb

So right now I have a schema for boxes, a box can contain objects or it can contain other boxes:

my schema for boxes looks like this:

```
var box =  new Schema({
    boxId: ObjectId,
    boxContents: [{
        contentType: {
            type: String,
            enum: ["box", "object"]
        },
        typeId: {
            subBox: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'box'
            },
            subObject: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'object'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

I made sure to have my 'ref' labeled accordingly with the model names so I don't believe that is the problem. I create a new document like so:

```
var box1 = new Box({
    contents: [{
        contentType: 'object',
        typeId: {
            subObject: object1._id
        }
    }]
});
```

When I use:

```
Control.find({}).populate('contents.typeId')
.exec(function(error, posts) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(posts, null, "\t"));
});
```

It doesn't populate the subBox and subObject fields :( If I try to access the subBox or subObject fields, it gives me undefined. 
What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Does that `subObject` with that `_id` exists in the database?

Comment: Yes it does, I added both the subObject and the subBox and when I look through the database both show up

Comment: Can you update your question with the sample objects present in your database?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get a model of the collection:

```js
var BoxModel = mongoose.connect(dbURI).model("box", box);
```

boxContents is in schema, but in the object is contents, that should be modified.
To create an object to be save, you need to use the model in that way, and then you can get your populated data this way:

```js
var box1 = new BoxModel({
    boxContents: [{
        contentType: 'object',
        typeId: {
            subObject: object1._id
        }
    }]
});


BoxModel.find({}).populate('boxContents.typeId');
OR
BoxModel.find({}).populate({path:'boxContents.typeId'});
```